# Angular Schema Form - "required" not working select and checkbox fields

Tags: angularjs, validation, required, angular-schema-form, tv4

I'm new to Angular Schema Form and having some issues with `select` and `checkbox` fields `required` validation.

Under `$scope.schema` I have the select field named `designation`:

```
"designation": {
    "title": "Designation",
    "type": "select",
    "default": undefined
}
```

`$scope.form` (declaring `designation` and `agreeTerms`):

```
{
    "key": "designation",
    "type": "select",
    "title": "Designation",
    "titleMap": [
        { value: undefined, name: "Select a designation" }, // first value
        { value: "Andersson", name: "Andersson" },
        { value: "Johansson", name: "Johansson" },
        { value: "other", name: "Something else..."}
    ]
},
{
    "key": "agreeTerms",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "title": "I agree to ..."
}
```

Both `designation` and `agreeTerms` are defined in the schema's `required` property.

When I submit the form, both fields however pass the `required` validation.  What I'm expecting the UI to show are the `Required` messages underneath/after the fields.  That is not happening.

Things I've tried:

- assign first value of the select field to `''` and `null` and match that with the schema default value.
- change the `select` field type to `object` in the schema; this worked and passed the required validation but the property didn't show up in the model

Please help :)

Comment: Looks AngularJS not Angular?

Comment: @siva636 yes my bad.  Thanks to yerkon for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the schema type to `string` as `select` is not a valid schema `type` property.

```
"designation": {
    "title": "Designation",
    "type": "string",
    "default": undefined
}
```

Then in your form tag you should have **ng-submit="submitForm(ngform,modelData)"**:

```
<form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="model" ng-submit="submitForm(ngform,modelData)" sf-options="option"></form>
```

Then within your controller you can broadcast on submit to validate:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(form) {
    // First we broadcast an event so all fields validate themselves
    $scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate');
};
```